# Scaling out HTTP parallel copies in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a copy activity ,running on a self-hosted IR, which is hitting thousands of different urls in a for-each activity , and have scaled it out even further by running the pipeline inside another foreach activity.
Each url downloads a unique image (25 kb on avg).
Though I can see multiple parallel copy activities being initiated as a result of this , but I am not getting the optimum throughput.
The copy activities are being queued far too long (avg 20 mins) to download a 25 kb file each.
A screen grab of IR shows not too high resource consumption on the other hand.

Is my IR throttling the activities to 1 http copy activity at a time ?

[image: IRcScreen Grabs][image]